# Add more ticks in plotly log scale

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

I need to add 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.... ticks on the y-axis. My chart is very tall, so I have enough room to do this. How can I do this?

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [7, 8],
  y: [1, 10000000000],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  width: 500,
  height: 800,
  xaxis: {
    autorange: true
  },
  yaxis: {
    type: 'log',
    dtick: 1,
    autorange: true
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to set `dtick: 'D1'`. @see [`dtick`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-dtick)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this is only a partial solution. Next to the numbers `2, 3, 4...` there are no letters `k, M, B...` for thousands, millions, billions...

Comment: This would be redundant, those are the steps in between ticks, usually text is minimized for smaller steps. You can still set the ticks manually, @see `tickmode`, `tickvals` and `ticktext`.

Comment: It won't be redundant if your graph has a high heihgt with a large vertical scroll slider. It turns out that in some parts of the graph it is not clear whether it is `k`, `M` or `B`.